# Problema com caracteres especiais

Tags: java, android, android-studio

eu tenho uma aplicação que baixa um arquivo csv de um servidor ftp e dentro desse arquivo contem informações de produtos e o app deve inserir-las em um banco, porém os caracteres especiais estão vindo "zuados", como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então fui olhar o arquivo csv dentro do android monitor para ver se estava tudo ok com o produto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esta certinhos, então debuguei o app

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

cheguei a conclusão de que esta ocorrendo no momento que o app busca as informações do arquivo CSV para inserir no banco, porém não faço ideia de como concertar este problema alguém pode me ajudar?

**Classe de importação:**

```
public void importarBanco(){
        try{
            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File fileProduto = new File(path, "/Import/produto.csv");
            FileInputStream produtoStream = new FileInputStream(fileProduto);
            BufferedReader lerArqProduto = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(produtoStream));
            String proLinha = lerArqProduto.readLine();

            while (proLinha != null){
                String[] proDados = proLinha.split(";");
                String codigo = proDados[0];
                String barras = proDados[1];
                String descricao = proDados[2];
                String venda1 = proDados[3];
                String venda2 = proDados[4];
                String venda3 = proDados[5];

                String resultado = proCrud.insereProduto(codigo, barras, descricao, venda1, venda2, venda3);
                proLinha = lerArqProduto.readLine();
            }
            lerArqProduto.close();

            File fileCliente = new File(path, "/Import/cliente.csv");
            FileInputStream clienteStrem = new FileInputStream(fileCliente);
            BufferedReader lerArqCliente = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clienteStrem));
            String parLinha = lerArqCliente.readLine();

            while (parLinha != null){
                String[] parDados = parLinha.split(";");
                String codigo = parDados[0];
                String nome = parDados[1];
                String cpf = parDados[2];
                String rg = parDados[3];
                String endereco = parDados[4];
                String bairro = parDados[5];
                String municipio = parDados[6];
                String uf = parDados[7];

                String resultado = parCrud.insereCliente(codigo, nome, cpf, rg, endereco, bairro,
                        municipio, uf);
                parLinha = lerArqCliente.readLine();
            }
            lerArqCliente.close();

            File fileLogin = new File(path, "/Import/login.csv");
            FileInputStream loginStream = new FileInputStream(fileLogin);
            BufferedReader lerArqLogin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(loginStream));
            String logLinha = lerArqLogin.readLine();

            while(logLinha != null){
                String[] logDados = logLinha.split(";");
                String usuario = logDados[0];
                String senha = logDados[1];

                String resultado = lCrud.insereLogin(usuario, senha);
                logLinha = lerArqLogin.readLine();
            }
            lerArqLogin.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não tem como adicionar algo como `charset = UTF-8` ou `charset = Windows-1252`

Comment: Sempre que você tiver esse problema, pode apostar que a causa é encoding. Acho que o comentário do R. Santos deve ser uma pergunta. Enfim, tenta carregar o CSV indicando um encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No momento que você carrega o arquivo para o `BufferedReader`, passe o charset como parâmetro.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fileProduto = new File(path, "/Import/produto.csv");
FileInputStream produtoStream = new FileInputStream(fileProduto);
BufferedReader lerArqProduto = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(produtoStream, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar declarar o `FileOutPutStream` assim:

```
 new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8"));
```